# azure web application not working from azure--no errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, azure

I created a webapplication using Visual Studio2010 MVC3 .I am able to run this application successfully on my computer emulator.Then I deployed this to azure and is not working.I cant see any errors .The only message I can see on screen is "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage " .Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the MVC3 template sets up session state management via SQL Express (you can verify this by looking at web.config). This works great locally but not in Windows Azure, since SQL Express won't be running there. Just change your database connection to point to SQL Azure (or disable session state) and hopefully you'll be back up and running again.

Nate Totten wrote a bit more on this topic, [here](http://blog.ntotten.com/2011/08/03/windows-azure-tools-1-4-released/).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some connection problem, not your code problem since you got the "internet explorer cannot display the website".

I would suggest you RDC to your VM and open the IIS and browse your website, to check if the deployment is correct. And then you can try to go to your website from you machine by the VIP instead of its domain name. For example http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/ instead of http://yourwebsite.cloudapp.net/. If it works then I think you'd better recreate the hosted service and have another try.

HTH